# How to define ForEach typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to iterate array using forEach but getting typescript warning
getting error `Void is not assignable to > parameter of type '() => void'`

```
Object.keys(nodes).forEach(function visit(idstr: string, ancestors: any[]) {
      let node = nodes[idstr],id = node.id;

      if (visited[idstr]) return;
      if (!Array.isArray(ancestors)) {ancestors = [];}

      ancestors.push(id);
      visited[idstr] = true;
      node.afters.forEach(function (afterID) {
        if (ancestors.indexOf(afterID) >= 0)
          throw new Error('closed chain : ' + afterID + ' is in ' + id);
          visit(afterID.toString(), ancestors.map(function (v) { return v }));
      });
      sorted.unshift(id);
    });
```

Comment: The first parameter of forEach is a callback function. This is the function that gets executed for each element of an array and the first two arguments it takes are: `element` and`index`. `element` is the current element of an array being processed and index is the index of said element. `index` should be of type number, but in your case you provide `ancestors: any[]`, which is incompatible. Without more context I can't really provide more help. forEach reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#parameters

Comment: my callback function is visit which accepts two argument idString and ancestor,
I want to loop on nodes and create sorted key. If i ignore typescript, i can run the method.
@pakut2

Comment: @KunalVashist "my callback function is visit which accepts two argument idString and ancestor" but `forEach()` will call it with `visit(idstr:string, index:number, idstrings:string[])` and `index:number` and `ancestors:any[]` are not compatible types.

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your code to be a [mre] suitable for demonstrating your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  Right now `nodes`, `visted`, and `sorted` are not defined, so I can't reproduce. (And you have an implicit `any` problem in there too).  I can *try* to fix it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wER1ON) but I can't test it (since things aren't defined) .  If you do decide to fix the example to be reproducible and want me to take another look, please comment and mention @jcalz so I get notified.